# Windows Phone 7 and unsafe code

Tags: .net, windows-phone-7

Does anybody know will it be allowed to use unsafe code in the future updates of Windows Phone 7. It's really an awkward situation to be not allowed to use unsafe blocks in C# (especially in game development).

Comment: I suspect that unless you are in the WP7 team this calls for speculation...

Comment: This question isn't useful but I am curious as to what unsafe code you could need to run, can you give an example?

Comment: Its stupid you can't do:: public unsafe struct SomeStruct {public fixed float Values[3];}

Answer (score 3):

Currently No - and I am pretty much sure it wont due to security issues and the whole sandboxing principle.

Answer (score 2):

If Microsoft every let an app developer crush a phone, then **Microsoft would get all the blame**.   Therefore I don’t think normal app developer will ever be allowed to use “unsafe code”,   if you your name is Nokia you may get a different answer...

However I expect over time there will be a “safe” way to do most of what you wish to do with “unsafe” code and the system will be better at detaching when the checks that slow down safe code can be removed without issues.

What is the real issue you are facing?

Comment: I've got some problems with creating a particle system. There's modifiers I'm using for create effects and in this modifiers I have to enumerate particles every time for every effect and it isn't well to check array bounds.